# Scrapy Playwright AttributeError: 'ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler' object has no attribute 'contexts'

Tags: python, scrapy, attributeerror, playwright, playwright-python

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageCoroutine
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import asyncio
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

class NewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "news"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.nst.com.my/news/crime-courts',
            callback = self.parse,        
            meta = dict(
            playwright = True,
            playwright_include_page = True,
            playwright_page_coroutines = [
                PageCoroutine('wait_for_selector', 'div#article-teaser'),
                ]
        ))

    async def parse(self, response):
        yield{
            'text' : response.text
        }
```

My program code is shown above.
I'm using ***Scrapy*** and ***Playwright*** to render the JavaScript content for New Strait Times website, but when I run this command **scrapy crawl news -O news.json**, it gives Attribute Error. I run this command on Windows VS Code without the virtual environment.
The setting is following this link: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright

After I use the command, it gives me output as shown below.

```
    PS C:\Users\THINKPAD\Downloads\news> scrapy crawl news -O news.json
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.5.1 started (bot: news)
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.8.0.0, libxml2 2.9.12, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 22.1.0, Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 22.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021), cryptography 36.0.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.windows_events._WindowsSelectorEventLoop
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'news',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'news.spiders',
 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['news.spiders'],
 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 0168f84b4969ba23
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [asyncio] ERROR: Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-3' coro=<Connection.run() done, defined at C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py:174> exception=NotImplementedError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 181, in run
    await self._transport.connect()
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_transport.py", line 140, in connect
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_transport.py", line 128, in connect
    self._proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\subprocess.py", line 218, in create_subprocess_exec
    transport, protocol = await loop.subprocess_exec(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1652, in subprocess_exec
    transport = await self._make_subprocess_transport(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 493, in _make_subprocess_transport
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [asyncio] ERROR: Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-4' coro=<Connection.run() done, defined at C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py:174> exception=NotImplementedError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 181, in run
    await self._transport.connect()
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_transport.py", line 140, in connect
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_transport.py", line 128, in connect
    self._proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\subprocess.py", line 218, in create_subprocess_exec
    transport, protocol = await loop.subprocess_exec(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1652, in subprocess_exec
    transport = await self._make_subprocess_transport(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 493, in _make_subprocess_transport
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler._engine_started of <scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler object at 0x00000242D5336C50>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1030, in adapt
    extracted = result.result()
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy_playwright\handler.py", line 115, in _launch_browser
    self.playwright = await self.playwright_context_manager.start()
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\async_api\_context_manager.py", line 51, in start
    return await self.__aenter__()
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\async_api\_context_manager.py", line 46, in __aenter__
    playwright = AsyncPlaywright(next(iter(done)).result())
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 181, in run
    await self._transport.connect()
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_transport.py", line 140, in connect
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_transport.py", line 128, in connect
    self._proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\subprocess.py", line 218, in create_subprocess_exec
    transport, protocol = await loop.subprocess_exec(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1652, in subprocess_exec
    transport = await self._make_subprocess_transport(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 493, in _make_subprocess_transport
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
2022-03-10 10:36:12 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler._engine_started of <scrapy_playwright.handler.ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler object at 0x00000242D564D570>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1030, in adapt
    extracted = result.result()
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy_playwright\handler.py", line 115, in _launch_browser
    self.playwright = await self.playwright_context_manager.start()
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\async_api\_context_manager.py", line 51, in start
    return await self.__aenter__()
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\async_api\_context_manager.py", line 46, in __aenter__
    playwright = AsyncPlaywright(next(iter(done)).result())
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_connection.py", line 181, in run
    await self._transport.connect()
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_transport.py", line 140, in connect
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playwright\_impl\_transport.py", line 128, in connect
    self._proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\subprocess.py", line 218, in create_subprocess_exec
    transport, protocol = await loop.subprocess_exec(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1652, in subprocess_exec
    transport = await self._make_subprocess_transport(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 493, in _make_subprocess_transport
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
2022-03-10 10:36:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.nst.com.my/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2022-03-10 10:36:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.nst.com.my/news/crime-courts>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1656, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 489, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator       
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
    return (yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider))
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1030, in adapt
    extracted = result.result()
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy_playwright\handler.py", line 175, in _download_request
    page = await self._create_page(request)
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy_playwright\handler.py", line 140, in _create_page
    context = self.contexts.get(context_name)
AttributeError: 'ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler' object has no attribute 'contexts'
2022-03-10 10:36:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2022-03-10 10:36:18 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/builtins.AttributeError': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 618,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 914,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 5.767382,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 10, 2, 36, 18, 692007),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/ERROR': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 10, 2, 36, 12, 924625)}
2022-03-10 10:36:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2022-03-10 10:36:18 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method DownloadHandlers._close of <scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.DownloadHandlers object at 0x00000242D5335090>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1656, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 489, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator       
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\__init__.py", line 81, in _close
    yield dh.close()
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1656, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = current_context.run(
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 489, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator       
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy_playwright\handler.py", line 158, in close
    yield deferred_from_coro(self._close())
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1030, in adapt
    extracted = result.result()
  File "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy_playwright\handler.py", line 161, in _close
    self.contexts.clear()
AttributeError: 'ScrapyPlaywrightDownloadHandler' object has no attribute 'contexts'
```

Comment: Please provide the full output of the command that includes the stack trace.

Comment: I've edited my question by attaching the output of the command.

Comment: The NotImplementedError is the most relevant thing here, not the AttributeError (that is merely an error during cleanup, the problem being that the method that sets the "contexts" attribute could not even be executed). AFAIK it's currently not possible to run scrapy-playwright on Windows, please see https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright/issues/7.